# How to use nAnt to get latest of all files in a Visual Studio Solution?

Tags: msbuild, nant, sourcegear-vault

Is there a task or something that can accept an sln file and then get latest of each file in the sln?

Comment: I ended up having to create a custom function to just parse the sln file.

Answer (score 2):

Sourcegear [provides](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/downloads.html) custom NAnt taks to work with their repository. I don't know if they work based off the solution file, but you might want to give them a try and see if they'll help you.